# Power series expression of x in terms of y

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $y=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+.....$ be a power series in $R[[x]]$ such that $a_1$ is an unit in $R$.

Does there exists a way to express x as a power series of y with coefficients in $R$?
Thanks

Comment: As a start, I would recommend typing "reversion of series" into Google and seeing what comes up. If you find what you want that way, then you can come back and report to us.

Comment: A method like [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)?

Comment: Thanks to J.M., your link is helpful